# Convert C socket program to python

Tags: python, c, sockets

I have been trying to convert this receiver code in C to python..
The python code i have used doesn't seems to be receiving anything.. 
The C code for sender uses

```
        sendto(sid,buffer,1023,0,(struct sockaddr *)&saddr,sizeof(saddr));
```

What is the problem while converting the following code to python.

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<sys/types.h>
        #include<sys/socket.h>
        #include<netinet/in.h>
        #include<errno.h>
        #include<unistd.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        int main(char *argv[])
        {
        socklen_t sid,clen;
        char buffer[1024];
        struct sockaddr_in saddr,caddr;
        int n;
        sid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
        if(sid<0)
            perror("socket_create");
        bzero((char*)&saddr,sizeof(saddr));
        saddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        saddr.sin_port=htons(12346);
        saddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
        if(bind(sid,(struct sockaddr *)&saddr,sizeof(saddr))<0)
            perror("socket_bind");
        while(1)
        {
        clen=sizeof(caddr);
        bzero(buffer,1024);
        n=recvfrom(sid,buffer,1023,0,(struct sockaddr*)&caddr,&clen);
        if(n<0)
            perror("receive");
        printf("Array : %s\n", buffer);
        }
        close(sid);
        return 0;
        }
```

Python code i tried is

```
            import socket
            import sys
            from thread import *

            HOST = "127.0.0.1"   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
            PORT = 12346 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            print 'Socket created'

            #Bind socket to local host and port
            try:
                s.bind((HOST, PORT))
            except socket.error , msg:
                print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
                sys.exit()

            print 'Socket bind complete'

            #Start listening on socket
            s.listen(10)
            print 'Socket now listening'

            #Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
            def clientthread(conn):
                #Sending message to connected client
                conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n') #send only takes string

                #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
                while True:

                    #Receiving from client
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                    reply = 'OK...' + data
                    if not data:
                        break

                    conn.sendall(reply)

                #came out of loop
                conn.close()

            #now keep talking with the client
            while 1:
                #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

                #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
                start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

            s.close()
```

Comment: You should provide the Python port that you've tried..we can't help you if you don't provide an example of what is not working for you. We will not convert the function for you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/

Comment: I couldn't do anything with python..I was expecting someone to convert this code to python..

Comment: @user3492927 This isn't exactly a code conversion service, nor is it a "please write this for me" service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't convert the C code to Python right. In C, a UDP socket was created by

```
    sid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
```

whereas in Python you were creating a TCP socket by

```
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

and were using `listen()` and `accept()` as adequate for TCP connections - this cannot work when your sender uses UDP.

You just have to convert the C code straightforward to Python, e. g.

```
    n=recvfrom(sid,buffer,1023,0,(struct sockaddr*)&caddr,&clen);
```

to

```
        buffer, caddr = s.recvfrom(1023)
```